# LEFT JOIN latest row using a date column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select the latest row from a LEFT JOIN not on the main query. This is my SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   messages 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON messages.message_to = users.user_id 
                  OR messages.message_user = users.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN message_replies 
              ON messages.message_id = message_replies.message_reply_main 
       LEFT JOIN user_personal_information 
              ON users.user_id = 
                 user_personal_information.user_personal_information_user
```

I want to select the latest row from:

```
       LEFT JOIN message_replies 
              ON messages.message_id = message_replies.message_reply_main
```

My column is called: `message_reply_date` - how can I use that to LEFT JOIN the latest row?

`message_replies`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message_replies` (
  `message_reply_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_reply_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_reply_main` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_reply_message` text NOT NULL,
  `message_reply_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `message_reply_read` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am using this for the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE m.message_user = ? 
OR m.message_to = ? 
  AND m.message_deleted=0 
  AND m.message_permdeleted=0 
GROUP BY mr.message_reply_main 
ORDER BY mr.message_reply_date DESC
```

Comment: What if two replies have the same `message_reply_date`?  It's unlikely, but not impossible (and it might be less unlikely for synthetically-generated test data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood the question, i'll do it this simple way:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM messages 
        LEFT JOIN users 
            ON messages.message_to = users.user_id OR messages.message_user = users.user_id 
        LEFT JOIN message_replies 
            ON messages.message_id = message_replies.message_reply_main 
        LEFT JOIN user_personal_information 
            ON users.user_id = user_personal_information.user_personal_information_user 
    WHERE message_replies.message_reply_date = (SELECT MAX(message_reply_date) FROM message_replies WHERE message_reply_main = messages.message_id) 
        /* AND more criterias */
```

No grouping in the main query but just using a `MAX` evaluation of `message_reply_date` in a subquery regarding the `WHERE` criteria on `message_reply_date` itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "left join" method for getting the most recent message (as well as several others).  But in keeping with the preferred join method of the question:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages m LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON m.message_to = u.user_id OR m.message_user = u.user_id LEFT JOIN
     message_replies mr
     ON m.message_id = mr.message_reply_main LEFT JOIN
     user_personal_information upi
     ON u.user_id = upi.user_personal_information_user LEFT JOIN
     message_replies mr2
     ON mr2.message_reply_main = m.message_id AND
        mr2.message_reply_date > mr.message_reply_date
WHERE mr2.message_reply_main IS NULL;
```

I also added table aliases because they make a query easier to write and to read.

The idea is to match to the table again, but only for later messages.  Then, the `WHERE` clause checks that none exist -- so it has the latest one.

Comment: That seems to be getting the latest reply (the second reply) but if I reply again it's still showing the second reply until I repeat the last join :s

Comment: @randommman . . . I don't know what you mean by "it's still showing the second reply until I repeat the last join".  Of course, you get the latest reply when the query is run.  If the underlying data changes, you need to run the query again.

Comment: Okay, say for example a create a message and reply, the reply shows, if I reply again that comes up (which is should) but if I reply for a 3rd time the 2nd reply is still the last message to show even though it should be the 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   messages 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON messages.message_to = users.user_id 
                  OR messages.message_user = users.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN (  SELECT  *
                    ,       MAX(message_reply_date) OVER (PARTITION BY message_id) AS most_recent_message_reply_date
                    FROM    message_replies ) message_replies
                                            ON  messages.message_id = message_replies.message_reply_main 
                                            AND message_replies.message_reply_date = message_replies.most_recent_message_reply_date

       LEFT JOIN user_personal_information 
              ON users.user_id = 
                 user_personal_information.user_personal_information_user
```

I've substituted your direct call to the message_replies table with a Select that displays the table and the maximum reply date grouped by the message_id.  I've then included this in the join to filter all answers other than the one your looking for.

Have a go, any problem drop me a message, always happy to help.

Comment: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY messages.message_id) AS most_recent_message_reply_date ' at line 9 in

Comment: Sorry that code was written on MSSQL not MYSQL. Not sure if there is a direct equivalent nt in MySQL. Can you try running just the code in the inner select for me: SELECT  *
                    ,       MAX(message_reply_date) OVER (PARTITION BY message_id) AS most_recent_message_reply_date
                    FROM    message_replies

Comment: Looks like this approach isn't valid in MYSQL. Some things don't translate from MSSQL to MYSQL exactly. Hopefully it may give you ideas, and lead you to your answer.

Comment: Yes, you're using the window function version of `MAX()`.  MySQL does not currently support window functions, and probably never will.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is emulate the rank & partition functionality seen in MSSQL & PL/SQL, essentially ranking on date & partitioning by message_reply_main.

This can be done in MySQL using an outer join & a count on your partition, while using a < or > in the join for the ranking criteria. This allows you to do your standard join, but also where rank = 1, returning the largest date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   messages 
   LEFT JOIN users 
          ON messages.message_to = users.user_id 
              OR messages.message_user = users.user_id 
   LEFT JOIN (select mri.message_reply_main
              , mri.message_reply_date
              , mri.message_reply_message
              , mri.message_reply_read
              , count(mri2.message_reply_main) + 1 as rank
              FROM message_replies mri
              left join message_replies mri2 on mri.message_reply_date < mri2.message_reply_date 
              and mri.message_reply_main = mri2.message_reply_main
              group by mri.message_reply_main, mri.message_reply_message
                       , mri.message_reply_read, mri.message_reply_date) mr ON messages.message_id = mr.message_reply_man
                                                                            AND mr.rank = 1
   LEFT JOIN user_personal_information 
          ON users.user_id = 
             user_personal_information.user_personal_information_user
```

Comment: Using this method will return two rows if they contain the exact same datetime value (IE, both are of equal lateness) as they will both share rank 1.